# Issue with sorting an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning javascript and can't figure out the problem in my code below. I guess I misunderstand how arrays actually work.

The problem is that the alerted array is not actually sorted. I would be grateful for any insights on this:

[Here is a ready jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F7Rbr/6/).

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Test 1
    </title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type=
    "text/javascript">
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="items">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="1">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="2">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="3">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="4">Link 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var clickedLinks = [];
var passedItems = [];


// Collect clicked link IDs into an array and pass the array as an argument to shoplist()
$('.items a').click(function () {

if (clickedLinks.indexOf(this.id) != -1) {
    var linkIndex = clickedLinks.indexOf(this.id);
    clickedLinks.splice(linkIndex, 1);
} else {
    clickedLinks.push(this.id);
}

shoplist(clickedLinks);

});


function shoplist(ids) {
    passedItems.push(ids.slice());
    alert(passedItems.sort());
}
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Click Link 2
2. Click Link 1

**Expected Result:** 1, 2, 2

**Actual Result:** 2, 2, 1

**Things I've tried:**

```
function shoplist(ids) {
    passedItems.push(ids.slice());
    var newpi = passedItems.slice();
    alert(newpi.sort());
    }
```

Comment: You have an array of arrays. Try not pushing to passed items but just sort clickedlinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding an array, the result of `ids.slice()`, to another array. That's why the sort doesn't work as you expect. Use `concat` instead, if you want to add the contents of `ids` to the `passedItems` array:

```
passedItems = passedItems.concat(ids);
```

Also, instead of adding a string to the `ids` array, you should use `.push(parseInt(this.id))` instead, and then use:

```
passedItems.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, sort() method will always sort alphabetically whether you are passing integers or strings. To sort numerically you'll need to pass the sorting function as an argument, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12133066/932210

Answer (score 2):

I think you're using the [sort function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) wrong. If you want to use the sort function numerically, you have to include a sort function. If you want to sort things numerically you should use this function (provided in the link):

```
(function(a,b){return a-b});
```

So in your scenario for the newpi it would look like this:

```
newpi.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work:

http://jsfiddle.net/DZpDG/4/